# Advanced CSS HTML Window Resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

How did this site achieve this effect?

http://demicreative.com

Simply re-size the window you are viewing the site in and you will see it completely change to suit mobile.

How can one do this?!?

Please excuse the title if it seems misleading

Answer (score 9):

This is a technique called [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). In a few words, this technique is based on response differently depending on the size of the screen that the page is being rendered. That is why when you re-size the window, the content suits this "new" screen.

This can be accomplished using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), which allows the designer to target not only certain device classes, but inspect the physical characteristics of the device rendering the page.

So, for example, in your CSS you could have this piece of code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .column {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Which would float to the right all the elements of the class `.column` to the right, just when the screen width is smaller than 480px.

Comment: Since it's CSS3 it's not fully supported across all browsers though right?

Comment: Of course :). Enjoy responsive web design, is pretty cool and fun.

Comment: It won't work in older browsers out the box, but you can use the following script to enable media queries in older browsers: http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Answer (score 2):

You can use Get Sleleton to achieve something like that
http://www.getskeleton.com

Html5 Boilerplate
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/wiki/css

Answer (score 2):

It's called a media query.  CSS3 compliant.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

On your example link, this is a media query in their CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    background: #141414;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 105px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  h1 i {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

So that CSS will only be activated if the device has a max screen width of 480px. Essentially a phone, not a tablet or monitor.

Comment: Wow thank you! So all it takes is this simple tag and specify a width and it's done?

Comment: Yeppers it's pretty simple to implement :)

Comment: Since it's CSS3 it's not fully supported across all browsers though right?

Comment: Correct. Though the main point of media queries is to cater to mobile devices and none of those are using legacy IE, so there's really nothing to worry about.

Comment: This is true! Thanks a heap for the info buddy :-)